# Java Split String by colon on both side

Tags: java, regex

Can you suggest me an approach by which I can split a String which is like:

```
:31C:150318 
:31D:150425 IN BANGLADESH
:20:314015040086
```

So  I tried to parse that string with

```
:[A-za-z]|\\d:
```

This kind of regular expression, but it is not working . Please suggest me a regular expression by which I can split that string with 20 , 31C , 31D etc as Keys and  150318 , 150425 IN BANGLADESH etc as Values .

If I use string.split(":") then it would not serve my purpose. 
If a string is like:

:20: MY VALUES : ARE HERE

then It will split up into 3 string , and key 20 will be associated with "MY VALUES" , and "ARE HERE" will not associated with key 20 .

Comment: use string class split function  as split(":") on your string

Comment: Regex should rather look like this: `:([A-za-z0-9]+):(.+)` or this: `:([A-za-z0-9]{2,3}):(.+)`

Comment: Please explain what final output you are trying to obtain, decipher *key 20 will be associated with "MY VALUES" , and "ARE HERE" will not associated with key 20*. Do you mean you only need to split by the 2nd `:`? Have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP9wH6/1)

Comment: @michal.svec : WOW!! that was awesome !! works like charm ! Thanks boss. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use matching mechanism instead of splitting since you need to match a specific colon in the string.

The regex to get 2 groups between the first and second colon and also capture everything after the second colon will look like

```
^:([^:]*):(.*)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP9wH6/1). The `^` will assert the beginning of the string, `([^:]*)` will match and capture into Group 1 zero or more characters other than `:`, and `(.*)` will match and capture into Group 2 the rest of the string. `$` will assert the position at the end of a single line string (as `.` matches any symbol but a newline without `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier).

```
String s = ":20:AND:HERE";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^:([^:]*):(.*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Key: " + matcher.group(1) + ", Value: " + matcher.group(2) + "\n"); 
}
```

Result for this demo: `Key: 20, Value: AND:HERE`

Answer (score 0):

Try with split function of String class

```
String[] splited = string.split(":");
```

For your requirements:

```
  String c = ":31D:150425 IN BANGLADESH:todasdsa";
    c=c.substring(1);
    System.out.println("C="+c);
    String key= c.substring(0,c.indexOf(":"));
    String value = c.substring(c.indexOf(":")+1);
    System.out.println("key="+key+" value="+value);
```

Result:

```
C=31D:150425 IN BANGLADESH:todasdsa
key=31D value=150425 IN BANGLADESH:todasdsa
```

Comment: Yes I tried that , but what if a String is like : 
:20: MY VALUES : ARE HERE

Comment: Ok, so you just want to split by the seccond ":"

Comment: If I use string.split(":") then it would not serve my purpose. If a string is like:

:20: MY VALUES : ARE HERE

then It will split up into 3 string , and key 20 will be associated with "MY VALUES" , and "ARE HERE" will not associated with key 20 .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to split:

```
^[:]+([^:]+):
```